# async function does update iterator correctly at the begining but not at the end

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

In the code bellow I work with CSS DOM, which may be computation heavy. This is apparently necessary to access the `:after` selector. `renderItem` method will add a new item to the DOM (including it's after element) and this is the reason why I have used the `async` function and `await` for it's return in each iteration inside of `loadFromStorage`.

However, the `await` seems to not work correctly, or something weird happens inside of `renderItem` function. The `n` iterator is updated correctly at the beginning of the function (items are correctly rendered to the screen and the first `console.debug` prints a correct value in a correct order), but at the bottom, the second printed value, is always the last iteration value (which is 4 in my case, as I am trying to render 4 items from the local storage) and `getCSSRule` method is getting a wrong number.

```js
let books = []
let n = 0

const renderItem = async (entry, direction = 1) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
  li.classList.add('item')
  n += 1
  console.debug(`iter: ${n}`)
  li.id = (`item${n}`)
  await addCSSRule(`#item${n}:after`)
  li.innerText = entry.slice(0, entry.length - 13)
  if (direction === 1)
    ul.appendChild(li)
  else
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.firstChild)
  console.debug(`iter: ${n}`)
  const s = await getCSSRule(`#item${n}::after`).catch(() => {
    console.debug(`Failed to find ':after' selector of 'item${n}'`)
    return false
  })
  s.style.content = "\""+ entry.slice(entry.length - 13, entry.length) +"\""
  return true
}

const loadFromStorage = () => {
  books = localStorage.getItem('books').split('//')
  books.forEach(async (entry) => {
    await renderItem(entry)
  })
}

...
```

Console result (considering `localStorage.getItem('books').split('//')` returns 4 items):

```
iter: 1
iter: 2
iter: 3
iter: 4
iter: 4 // Printed x4
```

I been also trying to pass this `renderItem` method to `await` inside of a `Promise` object, which give me the same result. Also when I update the `n` iterator at the end of function the same thing happens, but at the beginning of it.

I am sorry if some terminology I have used is not correct in the context of JavaScript, I been not using this language for many years and currently I am trying to catch on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem here is that you're passing an async function to `forEach`, so even though you're `await`ing inside the body of it, `forEach` will not wait for the function itself. To illustrate the order of events here, say you have 4 books A, B, C, D. Your execution will look something like this.

- `renderItem(A)`
- `n += 1` (n is now 1)
- `console.log(n)` (logs 1)
- `` await addCSSRule(`#item${1}:after`) `` (This is a truly asynchronous event, and so this frees up the event loop to work on other things, namely the next elements in the `forEach`)
- `renderItem(B)`
- `n += 1` (2)
- `console.log(n)` (logs 2)
- ...
- `renderItem(C)` ... `n += 1` (3) ... `await addCSSRule`
- `renderItem(D)` ... `n += 1` (4) ... `await addCSSRule`

And then whenever the `addCSSRule` calls resolve `n` will always be `4` no matter which call you're in.

#### Solution

Use a [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) loop instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```js
for await (const entry of books) {
    await renderItem(entry);
}
```

Or a traditional for loop, and modify `renderItem` to take `n` as an argument

```js
for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    renderItem(books[i], i+1);
    // we don't need to await in this case, and we add 1 to i so that the 'n' value is 1-indexed to match your current behaviour.
}
```

I would prefer the latter option as it's best practice to avoid mutable global state (your `n` variable) - as it can lead to confusing control flow and issues just like the one you're having.

One other option is to set a local variable to the value of `n` after incrementing it inside `renderItem`, so that for the duration of that function the value won't change, but that seems like a very hacky workaround to me.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for tracing it all down. As I needed the global iterator, for other methods that also use `renderItem`, I went with something in  between of those two solutions: `for (const entry of books) { renderItem(entry, ++book_id) }`.